# Does datatable created with DataTable.Copy() has datarow in same order?

Tags: c#

This question might be silly but I want to understand how **DataTable.Copy()** commands works.  It create a deep copy of original datatable, but does it always maintains the order of datarows from Original table?  As per my testing it always creates row in same order as it is in original table.  Is there a slight chance that order or rows in copied table can be different from original table?

Comment: Why do you even care?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that [`DataTable.Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a deep copy.  There is no guarantee of row order specified on MSDN, but if it were different, it would by definition not be a copy.

If you are curious what the current implementation does, have a look at the Microsoft Reference Source for [`DataTable.Copy()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,0bdc0c68889ce8b1).  You will see it first performs a [`Clone()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,78783cfa5ea4d91e).  Then, it performs a row-by-row copy.  So yes, the current implementation will preserve the row order.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I have a recent experience worth note. My situation is using dynamically created columns from a user created forms designer. The reporting on this relies on the Fill(DataTable) method of the SqlDataAdapter in order to get the unknown column names. I'll spare you the details, but the column names is why I used a DataTable to easily display the data on the site.
The point is, certain columns needed to be altered or removed for the Excel download that differed from the paged report on the site. This is basically a schema change in the resulting data table, which you can't do with existing rows. So, I was using the .Clone() during the process of creating a new DataTable to create the Excel where the schema could be altered. I was not able to keep the order of the source data during this processing using .Clone() where columns had to be altered or removed. I had to manage the results and copying of the data manually to get the altered schema and DataSet in the original order. This proved true when I tried to add it into a DataView and use the .Sort = "Column ASC" as well.
Regards

BTW, the alterations were to define DateTime formatting and to force typeof(string) on some data that could not lose zeros in Excel.